# Append object parent key to children

Tags: javascript

I have the following object given:

```json
{
  "groupA": [
    {data: 'foo'},
    {data: 'bar'}
  ],
  "groupB": [
    {data: 'hi'},
    {data: 'mom'}
  ]
}
```

I would like to append the parent object keys to all its array items like so:

```json
{
  "groupA": [
    {data: 'foo', set: 'groupA'},
    {data: 'bar', set: 'groupA'}
  ],
  "groupB": [
    {data: 'hi', set: 'groupB'},
    {data: 'mom', set: 'groupB'}
  ]
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: please may you share a [mcve] of what you've tried so far?

Comment: try `Object.keys(arr)` to get all key name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop and set each item

```js
const obj = {
  "groupA": [
    {data: 'foo'},
    {data: 'bar'}
  ],
  "groupB": [
    {data: 'hi'},
    {data: 'mom'}
  ]
};
Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key,val]) => val.forEach(item => item.set=key))
console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a immutable version that give you a new object using `Object.fromEntries` `Object.entries` and `map`

```js
const data = {
  "groupA": [{
      data: 'foo'
    },
    {
      data: 'bar'
    }
  ],
  "groupB": [{
      data: 'hi'
    },
    {
      data: 'mom'
    }
  ]
}

const withGroup = Object.fromEntries(
     Object.entries(data).map(([set, items]) => [set, items.map(i => ({ ...i,set}))])
)

console.log(withGroup)
```

Comment: I would not use `i` for item, since it is really confusing to the many ppl who use i for index

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply by looping over the object and mapping the arrays, like this:

```
const data = {
  "groupA": [
    {data: 'foo'},
    {data: 'bar'}
  ],
  "groupB": [
    {data: 'hi'},
    {data: 'mom'}
  ]
};

Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
    data[key] = data[key].map(rec => ({...rec, set: key}));
})

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `Object.keys(arr)` to get all key name:

```js
let before = {
  "groupA": [
    {data: 'foo'},
    {data: 'bar'}
  ],
  "groupB": [
    {data: 'hi'},
    {data: 'mom'}
  ]
}

let after = {}
Object.keys(before).map((key) => {
    let data = before[key].map((x) => { 
        x.set = key
        return x
    })
    after[key] = data 
})
console.log(before)
console.log(after)
```

==========

**[UPDATE]** Create `after` without changed `before`:

```js
    let before = {
    "groupA": [
        {data: 'foo'},
        {data: 'bar'}
    ],
    "groupB": [
        {data: 'hi'},
        {data: 'mom'}
    ]
}

let after = {}
Object.entries(before).forEach(([key, data]) => {
    after[key] = data.map((before_value) => { 
        return { 
            ...before_value, 
            set: key
          }
    })
})
console.log(before)
console.log(after)
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Your code also changes the original so no need for "after"

Comment: thanks, do you know how can i create `after` without change `before`?

Comment: Use the spread syntax to copy the child objects instead of accessing them

Comment: thanks, I updated my code with spread syntax

Answer (score 0):

You can use `for...in` as well

```js
let data = {
  "groupA": [
    {data: 'foo'},
    {data: 'bar'}
  ],
  "groupB": [
    {data: 'hi'},
    {data: 'mom'}
  ]
}

for (const key in data) {
  data[key] = data[key].map(item => ({...item, set: key}))
}

console.log(data);
```